# Split url string based on known start and end, with optional unknown in between segments

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to split strings with a known starting segment and optional additional segments until a common endpoint.

```
eg.

https://example.com/folder/upload/v1/subfolder/asset.doc

https://example.com/folder/upload/temp_cache_folder_id/v1/subfolder/asset.doc
```

Basically need to remove anything between /upload/ and /v1/

Currently got as far as

```
string.split(/.*?(?=v1)/)
```

Not sure how to proceed looking back until /upload/ and return

```
[https://example.com/folder , v1/subfolder/asset.doc]
```

upload/temp_cache_folder_id is joined with certain env variables later so it isn't needed. That's why the split was done in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/^(.*?)\/upload\/.*?(v1.*)/
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/DXgXUI/1).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  upload                   'upload'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    v1                       'v1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const string = "https://example.com/folder/upload/v1/subfolder/asset.doc";
const [_, url, v1] = /^(.*?)\/upload\/.*?(v1.*)/.exec(string);
console.log("URL: " + url);
console.log("v1: " + v1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using split, you could match `/upload/` followed by at least as possible chars until to can assert `v1` to the right.

```
\/upload\/.*?\b(?=v1)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JyrYeI/1).

**Explanation**

- `\/upload\/` Match `/upload/`
- `.*?` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except a newline, as least as possbile
- `\b(?=v1)` A word boundary followed by a postive lookahead asserting `v1` at the right.

```js
[
  "https://example.com/folder/upload/v1/subfolder/asset.doc",
  "https://example.com/folder/upload/temp_cache_folder_id/v1/subfolder/asset.doc"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.split(/\/upload\/.*?\b(?=v1)/))
);
```